# upload a file with javascript websockets to python tornado server

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, tornado, filereader

I am attempting to upload a file with javascript and send the data via websockets to a python tornado server. I thought this was working as the file is created and stored on my server machine but when I try to open the newly created file, it is corrupt. 
Could anyone explain the best way to read the file in javascript and then how to save that data once it is received server side?

Here is the function I use for loading my file:

```
 HomeView.prototype.loadFile = function(dataTransfer)
 {
    var that = this;
    var filereader = new FileReader();
    filereader.file = dataTransfer.files[0];
    that.fileName = dataTransfer.files[0].name;
    filereader.onload = function(e) {
        // file is loaded now add it to the zip file
        that.fileData = e.target.result;
   }
  // load the file
  filereader.readAsBinaryString(dataTransfer.files[0]);
}
```

Sent using ws.send(JSON.stringify(msg)); where msg is a json object containing my file and a message type. EG {data: filedata, type: fileupload}
My python server then receives the file (data_str) and passes it to the following function to save it. I use xlsx file type here as an example. Normally I will parse the filename and store the exact file as it was uploaded.

```
 def save_file_from_data(self, data_str):
    """save the rubric file for a byte string"""
    try:
        # name the zip, open in binary mode 
        fh = open("newfile.xlsx", 'wb')
        # save file data after encoding in UTF-8 first
        fh.write(data_str.encode('utf-8'))
        fh.close() 
    except:
        print("error")
```

I have also tried fh.write(bytes(data_str, 'UTF-8')) when writing to the file.

Any suggestions or tips would be greatly appreciated,

KB

Comment: It appears that only .xlsx files are the problem (from the different types I have tested, .txt .html. xml .py .js). Anyone know why they are problematic?

Comment: `.xlsx` is a binary file format; those others are all text. JSON cannot contain binary data directly; are you encoding the file (e.g. with base64) when wrapping it with json? You should have bytes instead of characters when writing the file; it shouldn't be necessary to mention 'utf8' at this point.

Comment: ah I see.. Thank you, this really had me confused! I was using JSON.stringify() when sending but I know how to fix it now, thanks again!